# How can I determine which named property (or properties) are filling my exchange 2007 information store?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

I'm experiencing the following error on an Exchange 2007 server:

---

Event ID: 9667
Type: Error
Category: General
Source: msgidNamedPropsQuotaError
Description: Failed to create a new named property for database "" because the number of named properties reached the quota limit (). User attempting to create the named property: . Named property GUID: . Named property name/id: .

---

I understand that this can occur if the exchange information store is filling up with named properties... but I don't know how to determine which specific named property is at fault here.  Is there a way to examine the DB for this type of info to see if there's a specific recurring named property that is consuming resources?

-M

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a matter of a single named property causing this, rather a profusion of them. I've had this exact problem several times in the past couple years. In the beginning, Microsoft saw fit to allow any old X header in mail to promote to a named property in Exchange. They also saw fit to hard code the maximum number of named properties. Time passes, and jokers do this kind of thing in headers:

```
 X-IHateYou: True
```

Or other software packages doing stupid stuff like:

```
 X-20010122113201: True
```

Which Outlook dutifully promoted to a NamedProperty. And people started running out of NamedProperties quota. Microsoft has put out a few articles on this over the years.

A few resources:

- [Named Properties, X-Headers, and You](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/04/06/451003.aspx)
- [Named Properties, Round 2: What lies Ahead](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/06/11/451596.aspx)
- [Increasing the Named Properties Quota](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851493(EXCHG.80).aspx)

What you are seeing is not one NamedProperty getting used to exhaustion, you actually WANT those to go to NamedProperties. What you don't want are X-headers that you don't give a wet noodle for getting promoted if it doesn't have to. Exchange 2007 has had some progress on this issue in recent service-packs and update rollups as the linked articles suggest. However, if you're running into it now, the only thing left is to increase your NamedProperties quota.

Comment: Hi Sysadmin1138.  Thanks for the explanation, that makes more sense.  I have some follow-up questions: 1) Is there anyway to view/search the named properties? 2) It looks like rollup 8 may have filtered of these pesky x-headers out.  Is there a way to flush out the ones that already exist in named properties?

Comment: I don't know of a way to dig into the system and look up named-properties short of writing my own MAPI-based app to do just that. Once a named-property is assigned, it is assigned for the life of that system. There is no recycling, unfortunately.