# Benign Email Headers

Tags: linux, email, email-server, smtp-headers

On our server, we have two separate email systems: if it's a long queue of recipients, then we store it in a queue to be sent in a cron.  If it's less than X number of recipients, then it sends immediately.  Both are built in PHP with MySQL storing the queue.

However, there is a question of whether or not this is working 100%.  In order to determine which email system is sending the email, I'd like to add a simple, completely meaningless email header like foo:bar or something like that.

So, my question is: is this at all possible?  Would a foo:bar email header screw anything up?  I'm not very well versed on what's under the hood, here and it's a live system sending out thousands of emails per hour.

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify.

Comment: I'd just like to be 100% certain that this is not only possible, but will be completely benign.  Google was returning results about unsafe email headers, and I wanted to know if there will be problems just passing foo:bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some `X-Foo: cron` header (with the `X-` prefix!) isn't a problem, you can add them as you like.

**Edit**

I forgot about https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648. So scrap the `X-` part.

Comment: The only issue I'm aware of with adding more distinct header lines is the per-mail database limit in some versions of Exchange (see for example http://serverfault.com/questions/130624/how-can-i-determine-which-named-property-or-properties-are-filling-my-exchange).